# Can runhaskell pick up options from .ghci?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci, runhaskell

Many people include `.ghci` files in their haskell projects to include needed options to load modules into `ghci`. Here's an example:

```
:set -isrc -itest -iexamples -packagehspec2
```

However when trying to run a file containing `main` through `runhaskell` one has to repeat all these options, e.g.:

```
runhaskell -isrc -itest -iexamples -packagehspec2 test/Spec.hs
```

Is there a good way to let `runhaskell` pick up the options from the `.ghci` file?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any way to make `runhaskell` work.  What I do is just pipe `"main"` to ghci:

```
$ echo main | ghci -v0 test/Spec.hs
```

If you want to pass command-line arguments, that works too:

```
$ echo ':main -m "behaves correct"' | ghci -v0 test/Spec.hs
```

Or you can wrap it up in a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell
>import System.IO
>import System.Environment
>import System.Exit
>import System.Process
>
>main :: IO ()
>main = do
>  source:args <- getArgs
>  (Just h, Nothing, Nothing, pid) <- createProcess (proc "ghci" ["-v0", source]) {std_in = CreatePipe}
>  hPutStr h ("import System.Environment\nSystem.Environment.withArgs " ++ show args ++ " main\n")
>  hClose h
>  waitForProcess pid >>= exitWith
```

Which can be used like so:

```
$ ./run.lhs test/Spec.hs -m "behaves correct"
```